# How long it takes of app name to get updated in play store?

Tags: android, playback

we want to change only play store display name of my app , I don't want to update new APK

Answer (score 0):

Due to adjusted work schedules at this time, you may experience longer than usual review times for your app. It can take up to 1 week.

Answer (score 0):

After submit it will take 24 hours to update your app info in the play store.

Answer (score 0):

It takes up to 1 week to update (due to COVID-19) if your application is approved and you still do not see any changes you just have to check with other phones or check for your Google Play console application. If you want to update your application name it is necessary to update your application, it doesn't require any new things you update the same version of your application (If it is not a version update, it takes up to 24-48 hours to see any changes in your application on play store).

Answer (score 0):

2 hours, nowadays. But sometimes it can take upto 24hours.

Answer (score 0):

For an application version upgrade, the review could take up to 24 hours.
If it is not a version upgrade, it may take 24 to 48 hours.